# Solr 3.5 field type

Tags: solr, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I'm using Solr 3.5 in the application that I'm working currently. I have defined few field types as custom which would be a prefixed values.

Mostly they are price which differs for each and every prefix.

Example 123_34.99 will define the price "34.99" in the store "123".

I need to know whether any exact/similar Out of Box fieldtype is there in Solr 4.1.0 to handle the above mentioned field types.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a better approach to store your data would be to use [Solr dynamic fields](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields). Instead of storing your data as 123_34.99, wouldn't you want to store it in a `price_STOREID` field like

```
price_123 = 34.99
```

Or is there a specific reason you want to store it as `123_34.99`?